# SharePoint 2010 Motools JavaScript incompatibility

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, mootools, slideshow

I created a JavaScript Slideshow base on [Slideshow2](https://code.google.com/p/slideshow/) using Mootools. It works great stand-alone. I decided to incorporate it into my SharePoint 2010 Master Page and at first glance it was working great, but for some strange reason other native SharePoint javascript code on the page stopped working. Some JavaScript code such as the “Create” button from “View All site content” does nothing and some drop downs from the global navigation menu. I first noticed when I tried to approve the saved master.page and when I clicked on Approve nothing happened.

I began to delete all my JavaScript code and from process of elimination noticed that just by leaving the line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/javascript/mootools-1.3.2-core.js"></script>` causes the error. Every other line doesn’t seem to affect the other JavaScript code. I even substituted it to the most recent version and got the same result: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/javascript/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that MooTools and the SharePoint script libraries are battling over the '$' alias. According to MooTools, the more recent versions will attempt to detect the dollar alias being used and not steal it. This is dependent on the Mootools library being loaded after other scripts. See ["The Dollar Safe Mode"](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/) for more info.

I would suggest moving MooTools to the bottom of your Master Page (just before the closing `body` tag), and seeing if that helps. I've not used MooTools, but I assume that there is something similar to jQuery's [`$(document).ready()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) method that allows you to invoke your MooTools code only after the core library has been loaded.

Comment: Yes, the client side functionality of the ECM components (especially ULS logging) will rely on $ and $$ monikers.  Mootools uses them both, [Element Reference](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element).  I'd recommend to follow direction with [Mootools Safe Mode](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/) and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried putting the script tag at the end right before the </body> tag, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this code to the master-page to include MooTools library:
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="MooToolsJS" runat="server" Name="/_catalogs/javascript/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />

Comment: I had a hard time trying to figure out where to put the JavaScript file, but later foud it in `\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033`, but it still behaves the same.

Comment: @Rick - Did you try using the compressed or uncompressed version of MooTools? I can load the `1.4.5-full-compat.js` into the default "Night and Day" master page and everything works just fine.

Comment: I used the uncompressed version of 1.4.5-full-compat.js and the original mootools-1.3.2-core.js under v4 master page.

Comment: I tried enclosing all my JavaScript calls in the SharePoint:ScriptLink tag and actually no JavaScript at all works.I get the error on `home.aspx` "`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'addEvent' `"